# Update pyspark dataframe column with complex function

Tags: json, apache-spark, dataframe, hive, pyspark

Is it possible to update a hiveContext dataframe column in pyspark using a complex function not doable in a UDF?

I have a dataframe containing many columns, out of which 2 columns are called timestamp and data. I need to retrieve the timestamp from within the JSON string in data and update the timestamp column if the timestamp in data fulfills certain criteria. I know that that dataframes are immutable, but is possible to somehow build a new dataframe retaining all the columns of the old dataframe but updating the timstamp column?

Code illustrating what i would like to do:

```
def updateTime(row):
    import json

    THRESHOLD_TIME = 60 * 30
    client_timestamp = json.loads(row['data'])
    client_timestamp = float(client_timestamp['timestamp'])
    server_timestamp = float(row['timestamp'])
    if server_timestamp - client_timestamp <= THRESHOLD_TIME:
        new_row = .....  # copy contents of row
        new_row['timestamp'] = client_timestamp
        return new_row
    else:
        return row

df = df.map(updateTime)
```

I thought of mapping the row contents to a tuple and then converting it back to a dataframe with .toDF() but I can't find a way to copy the row contents into a tuple and then getting back the column names.

Comment: What about if you use an `UDF`?

Comment: Maybe this article can help: http://www.sparktutorials.net/using-sparksql-udfs-to-create-date-times-in-spark-1.5

Comment: Sorry i meant UDF instead of HDF... typo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you adapt your `updateTime` function to receive a Timestamp as parameter and return the new processed Timestamp, you can create an UDF and use it directly on the DataFrame's column:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType

myUDF = udf(updateTime, TimestampType())
df = df.withColumn("timestamp", myUDF(col("timestamp"))
```

However, in your case I think it's a little more complex:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType

myUDF = udf(getClientTime, TimestampType())
client_timestamp = myUDF(col("data"))
server_timestamp = col("timestamp")
condition = server_timestamp.cast("float") - client_timestamp.cast("float") <= THRESHOLD_TIME    

newCol =  when(condition, client_timestamp).otherwise(server_timestamp) 
newDF = df.withColumn("new_timestamp", newCol)
```

With this second approach, the function `getClientTime` receives a value from the `data` column and returns the client timestamp for this value. Then, you can use it to create a new column (`client_timestamp`) that contains this information. Finally you can use [`when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) to create the new column conditionally, based on the values of the `server_timestamp` column and the newly created `client_timestamp` column.

Reference:

- For more information about using UDFs in Spark, you can check the following article: http://www.sparktutorials.net/using-sparksql-udfs-to-create-date-times-in-spark-1.5
- The main documentation for the functions I used can be found in the [pyspark API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions)

Comment: Thanks! The method works with some minor changes. Looks like I didn't understand how UDFs worked previously. Edited myUDF to return StringType() instead and used df['column'] instead of col('column')